# How to add and delete customers to html using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Implement the showCustomers function so that it renders customers as list items. The first argument to the function, customers, is an array of objects with the name and email properties. The second argument to the function, targetList, is an unordered HTML list to which each customer should be added as a separate list item.

The name and email properties should be added as two paragraphs inside the list item. The email HTML element should not be present at first, and its HTML element should be added / removed when the name is clicked.

I managed to add the list but the remove function is not working. if anyone can help.

```js
let customers = [{
    name: "John",
    email: "john@example.com"
  },
  {
    name: "Mary",
    email: "mary@example.com"
  }
];

function addItem() {
  var ul = document.getElementById('customer');

  for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var paraName = document.createElement("p");
    var nameNode = document.createTextNode(customers[i]['name']);
    paraName.appendChild(nameNode);

    var paraEmail = document.createElement('p');
    var emailNode = document.createTextNode(customers[i]['email']);
    paraEmail.appendChild(emailNode);
    li.appendChild(paraName);
    li.appendChild(paraEmail);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}

addItem();

function removeItem() {
  nameNode.addEventListener('click', li.removeChild(nameNode));
}
removeItem();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://stacksnippets.net/js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id='customer'>
  </ul>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might also want to read the [Stack Overflow question checklist by Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Please run the snippet and observe the logs, the error message pretty explains what's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```js
  //This will give you 100% perfect result
  
  function showCustomers(customers, targetList){
     for(var customer in customers){
      let li = document.createElement('li');
      let p = document.createElement('p');
      li.appendChild(p);
     let name = document.createTextNode(customers[customer].name);
     p.appendChild(name);
     targetList.appendChild(li);
    }
    var first_P_elements =[...document.getElementsByTagName('li')];
     first_P_elements.forEach(function(el,i){
      el.children[0].addEventListener('click',function(){
       if(el.children.length>1){
         el.children[1].remove();
       }else 
       {
      let p2 = document.createElement('p');
      let email = document.createTextNode(customers[i].email);  
      p2.appendChild(email);
     this.parentElement.appendChild(p2);
           }
       });
    });
     }
    document.body.innerHTML = `<div><ul id="customers"></ul></div>`;
    let customers = [{name: "John", email: "john@example.com"},
                     {name: "Mary", email: "mary@example.com"}];
    showCustomers(customers, document.getElementById("customers"));
    let customerParagraph = document.querySelectorAll("li > p")[0];
    if(customerParagraph) {
      customerParagraph.click();
    }
    console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared nameNode in addItem function. Thus it can't be accessed from removeItem check out [JavaScript variable scopes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

And your logic to remove element is also wrong. you're directly using li, not the element on which the click event has happened. And also, the click event is of no use as you're applying it on nameNode. Because it is string and not a node. log it to see the content. you need to apply the event on the element and not the content. so you will need to apply the event on paraName.

As you can't access variables you used in the for loop, you will need to bind event listeners from inside of the for loop. And you'll have to check on which element the event happened, (e.target) and from it's parent element (li) remove the second child which is email.

```js
let customers = [{
    name: "John",
    email: "john@example.com"
},
{
    name: "Mary",
    email: "mary@example.com"
}
];

function addItem() {
    var ul = document.getElementById('customer');

    for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var paraName = document.createElement("p");
        var nameNode = document.createTextNode(customers[i]['name']);
        paraName.appendChild(nameNode);

        var paraEmail = document.createElement('p');
        var emailNode = document.createTextNode(customers[i]['email']);
        paraEmail.appendChild(emailNode);
        li.appendChild(paraName);
        li.appendChild(paraEmail);
        ul.appendChild(li);

        paraName.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            let x = e.target.parentElement;
           x.removeChild(x.childNodes[1]);
        })
    }
} 
addItem();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://stacksnippets.net/js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id='customer'>
  </ul>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'll leave on click add email functionality to you to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(let j = 0; j < lis.length; j++) {
    var p = lis[j].getElementsByTagName('p');
    let count = 0;
    p[0].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        var paraEmail = document.createElement('p');
        var emailNode = document.createTextNode(customers[j]['email']);
        paraEmail.appendChild(emailNode);
        let x = e.target.parentElement;
        if(count == 0) {
            x.appendChild(paraEmail);
            count = 1;
        } else if(count == 1) {
            e.target.nextElementSibling.remove();
            count = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: there are two <li> with one <p> at first step. therefore, you need to addEventListener by loop through <p> element under two <li> elements. you need a loop here. then, you need to variable count to check if email need to be appended or removed.